# Enviar dados para uma outra página através de um botão

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como resolver a seguinte situação:
Tenho uma página que possui um loop no qual ela mostra todos os posts de um posttype especifico, e em cada post coloquei um botão (sem funcionalidade por enquanto).

Gostaria de algum jeito fazer com que quando o usuário clicasse nesse botão, o post fosse salvo de alguma maneira e aparecesse em uma outra pagina chamado "meus posts", e claro, se a pessoa clicasse no botão de novo esse post sumiria da pagina "meus posts".

Já pesquisei plugins para isso, mas não rolou e agora estou tentando fazer algum código mesmo na mão, mas não tenho tanto conhecimento para isso. Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei grato.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT! Nos mostre algum código que você já tenha feito. Para podermos ajudar

Comment: Você está usando um banco de dados para guardar e controlar esses posts?

Comment: estou sim mysql workbanch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a melhor maneira de fazer isso é utilizando GET.
Você vai criar para cada botão um link que conterá 2 coisas:

1) O arquivo que vai fazer o tratamento do dado enviado.
2) O dado em si.

Em cada botão de post, coloque o endereço de um arquivo específico imprimindo logo em seguida, o id do post (ou qualquer outra identificação).

Segue exemplo abaixo:

`<div class="post">
      <div class="thumb"></div>
      <h3 class="post-title"><?php echo $post['name'];?></h3>
      <a href="save_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['id'];?>"></a>
</div>`

Perceba que logo após o endereço do link (href) eu imprimo um "?id=" (indicando o nome da variável que será passada e o id do post (que no seu caso será o valor que contém as informações do post. Imagine que o post em questão seja o post de id 50. O endereço impresso no href será:

`<a href="save_post.php?id=50"></a>`

Agora, crie o arquivo save_post.php que vai manipular este dado. Não sei exatamente como pretende criar a lógica de armazenar os "meus posts" mas para pegar a variável com o id do post, basta fazer o seguinte. em save_post.php coloque:

`$post_id = $_GET['id'];`

Pronto. Basta usar a variável $post_id da maneira que desejar pois ela conterá o id do post clicado.

Comment: nossa, perfeito vou fazer isso sim, obrigado!!!

Comment: E como eu faria para se eu clicar denovo, meio que ele jogar fora esses dados para poder sumir da outra pagina?

Comment: Isso vai depender de onde você vai armazenar os dados dos "meus posts".

Comment: entendi mano, obrigado!!

Comment: Conforme eu disse na explicação, no arquivo save_post.php você vai implementar a forma de armazenar estes dados. Na hora de remover você só precisa fazer o processo reverso.
Se fez um INSERT em alguma tabela com o ID do post, basta fazer o delete deste post buscando pelo ID.

Comment: hmmm, beleza ;)